# Show that a limit with natural logarithm does not exist (two variables)

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, logarithms

I can't prove this limit below doesn't exist. 
***$$\lim_{x \to 1 \; y \to 0} \frac {\ln(x + y)} {y}$$***
I already know that ***$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\ln(1 + x)} {x} = 1$$*** It seems absurd but the limit of two variables is different from ones.
Have you guys got any ideas. Tks.

Comment: You can try two different substitutions like $y=1-x$ which gives limit $0$ and $y=1-x^2$ which gives limit $1/2$ hence there is no well defined limit.

Comment: tks so much @ParamanandSingh, I've tried these substituitions. Eventually it ain't that hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the standard limit you quote, we can write
$$\frac {\ln(x + y)} {y}=\underbrace{\frac {\ln(1+(x-1 + y))}{x-1+y}}_{\substack{\downarrow\\ \strut1}}\frac {x -1+ y} {y},$$
so the limit, if any, is the same as that of
$$\frac{x-1+y}{y}=1+\frac{x-1}{y}.$$
However, using polar coordinates: $x=1+r\cos\theta,\; y=r\sin\theta$, it is easy to see that the limit of
$$\frac{x-1}{y}=\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$$
does not exist since its value would depend on $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

Put $x=1+\frac 1 n$ and $y =\frac 1 {n^{2}}$. Note that $\frac {\ln (1+\frac 1 n+\frac 1 {n^{2}})} {1/n^{2}}=\frac {\ln (1+\frac 1 n+\frac 1 {n^{2}})} {\frac 1 n+\frac 1 {n^{2}}} \frac {\frac 1 n+\frac 1 {n^{2}}} {1/n^{2}}\to (1)(\infty)=\infty$.